# How can I specify an availability zone for a spot request using cfncluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to pick the lowest price availability zone for a cluster using cfncluster. So far I can pick the region, but not the az with the following

```
cfncluster create -t [templateName] --region [region] [clusterName]
```

Is it possible to specify a single availability zone for the cluster?